# There are 3 red balls and 7 blue balls in a bag. We take 4 balls randomly from the bag without replacement.

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting at least $2$ blue balls?

When it asks for specific quantities of balls, i.e. $2$ red balls and $2$ blue balls, I understand to do

$\dfrac{\binom{3}{2}\cdot\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}}$

But how do I solve this when it says *at least*? I have tried computing $\binom{7}{2} + \binom{7}{3} + \binom{7}{4} \,etc. / \binom{10}{4}$, but this is incorrect.

The correct answer is $\frac{29}{30}$. Could someone please provide the steps on how to get to this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting how many blue balls are selected.

The question asks us to find $Pr(X\geq 2)$

Breaking apart via cases:

$Pr(X\geq 2)=Pr(X=2)+Pr(X=3)+Pr(X=4)$

In other words, to have *at least two*, this is the same as asking having *exactly two* or *exactly three* or *exactly four*.

You say you know how to calculate each of these specific cases.

It continues then as:

$$Pr(X\geq 2)=\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{2}+\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{3}+\binom{3}{0}\binom{7}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

Each term of which comes from multiplication principle:  Pick the red balls followed by pick the blue balls.

---

Alternatively, one can see that $Pr(X\geq 2) = 1-Pr(X<2) = 1-Pr(X=1)$ in this specific case since $Pr(X=0)=0$ (there are only three red balls to pick, we can't have picked four red)

We have then $1-\frac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{7}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}} = 1-\frac{1}{30}=\frac{29}{30}$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting  at least two blue balls is equal to $$1-\mathbb{P}(\text{getting at most one 1 blue ball})=1-\mathbb{P}(\text{getting 1 blue ball})-\mathbb{P}(\text{getting 0 blue balls}).$$